# TagLibSharp and MP4 files

Tags: c#, properties, media, taglib-sharp

I'm using TagLib# v2.1.0 and it does show namespaces TagLib.MPeg and TagLib.MPeg4, but I consistently get this error with .MP4 files that I deal with -

"Box header specified a size of {0} bytes but only {1} bytes left in the file"
(and TagLib.CorruptFileException is caught)

No problems with .WMV files.

I suspect from looking at the taglib# source that the MPeg namespaces are incomplete, aimed at Apple only (?).

I have resorted to using the Windows API CodePack for reading Properties (and the API probably allows writing enough of them).

If helpful in someone suggesting how I could use TagLib#, I can post some of the MediaInfo output for the MP4 files I use (they have been captured with rtmpdump, Adobe Flash Video, AVC video codec, YUV color space, ...)